# Filter dates stored as varchar in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, varchar

I am working with a MySQL database where dates are stored as varchar like this:

`'2013-01-31'` in column `cl_223`

I need to select only records from 2013 so I tried:

```
SELECT ..
FROM ....

Where cl_223 Like '2013'
```

But that does not seem to work.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Why store date as `VARCHAR`? Its length is never variable (unless you have some case you didn't mention). Also, keeping its data type as `DATE` will give you much more flexibility, moreover it will be foolproof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing a datettime value in a varchar column complicates some functionality on date time operations. But of course you can select your values writing such a query as follow

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE cl_223 LIKE '2013%'
```

But if you don't have any performance issue you can convert the varchar column to a datetime value and write stronger typed query like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(cl_223,'%Y-%m-%d2') BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
```

But if you need a date time value as a date time in your process you'd better store it in a datetime column instead of a varchar column.

Answer (score 3):

You must add `%` as a wildcard :

```
SELECT ..
FROM ....

WHERE cl_223 LIKE '2013%'
```

Comment: @Leeish : I did : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#Databases. So what ?

Answer (score 1):

The query should be

```
SELECT ..
FROM ....

Where cl_223 Like '2013%'
```

However, the better solution would be to store the dates as `DATE` data types.  If the dates in that column are always used in the format they're in now, the change would be backwards compatible.  It would also allow for easier processing of the date values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, G-Nugget. In this case I am just bolting a report on to an existing app which I do not have influence over - so I think I need to live with varchar.